# Executing batch command at target machine in vsto setup

Tags: windows-installer, vsto, installation

Need to run command for disabling UAC and configure Excel to RunAs administrator in VSTO Setup  progam.

```
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f  
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Unable to disable UAC  
goto :EOF
```

I have created VSTO Setup as mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx but not aware how to add this command in VSTO setup.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by disabling UAC? I suspect that you have an issue with your setup and have decided that disabling UAC is the solution, if so you could describe the issue. Needless to say, unless you're in a very specialized environment I doubt that customers would appreciate you disabling a major security feature, plus I don't think it works like that - it needs a reboot to take effect.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW!!  I need to load/unload COM AddIn and that requires excel to configure as Administrator and wanted to disable UAC so that it should not prompt for ok/cancel...My need is how to execute these commands through VSTO Setup..

Comment: I think you could use an [installer custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) code to run the BAT command within your installer setup.